# Set the selected item in ListView when a user enters Master / Detail from the detail screen if using a dynamic dataset

Tags: android, android-listview, master-detail

My app has a section that is perfect for the `Master / Detail` pattern.  I have implemented fragments in an effort to optimize for tablets.  Everything is going pretty smoothly, but I am curious what I should do if the user triggers the `Master / Detail` (which currently happens when the device is put into `landscape`) from the `DetailActivity`.

I tried switching to `landscape` on the `gmail` app when on an email detail, and it does in fact transition to a `Master / Detail` with the proper item in the `ListView` selected.

I could see this being simple if my `ListView` was backed by static data, but it is backed by `SQLite` data.  I thought about using a `position` value that would be passed to the `DetailActivity` for use when constructing the `ListFragment`, but I'm afraid that when my `ListFragment` is created and it requeries the database the data set may have changed, thus making the `position` value stale.

Comment: Are you updating the ListView dynamically or do the Values in SQLite stay the same ? So the ListView is only redisplayed with the same data ?

Comment: @inner_class7 I am using a `CursorAdapter` to back the `ListView`.  I want to assume that the database data could change between the time that the user is on the `DetailActivity` and the time that he or she changes the orientation.

Comment: Okay, I am a little confused by your approach. When you navigate your application and you have a Master / Detail view, how would the underlying data be changed without any user interaction. If you could explain a bit more I am willing to offer a solution of course.

Comment: Also, can you provide the code for the activity ? It would be most helpful.